# Photo in curriculum in top right corner

Tags: vertical-alignment, minipage, two-column, multicolumn, cv

I just need to add the photo in my curriculum, I have absolutely no idea on how to place it in the top right corner. I tried with `\smash`, but it had no effect whatsoever...

```
documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[UKenglish]{babel}
\usepackage[UKenglish]{isodate}
\usepackage[page]{appendix}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[space]{grffile}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[round]{natbib}
\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}
\usepackage{nopageno}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{datetime}
\usepackage{multicol}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{hidelinks = true,}

\newcolumntype{L}{>{\hsize=.190\hsize}X}
\newcolumntype{R}{>{\hsize=.85\hsize}X}
\newcolumntype{M}{>{\hsize=.28\hsize}X}
\newcolumntype{s}{>{\hsize=.5\hsize}X}

\hyphenpenalty=10000

\setlength\parindent{0pt}

\linespread{1.1}

\setlength{\extrarowheight}{2pt}

\begin{document}
\cleanlookdateon

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% PERSONAL DETAILS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

{\LARGE \textsc{\textbf{Matteo Bulgarelli}}} \\

Updated: {\monthname} \the\year  \\

\includegraphics[scale=0.2]{somepicture.jpg} % No idea on how to position this

Via San Pierino 25,\\
40013 Castel Maggiore, Bologna\\
Italy\\
email: \href{mailto:matteo.bulgarelli@student.uclouvain.be}{matteo.bulgarelli@student.uclouvain.be} \\

\medskip
\bigskip

\end{document}
```

I hope I didn't cut some environment necessary to run the code, I'm sorry, I tried to report the minimun, but as I took the template from a friend, I don't really know what the minimum reproducible code is...

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you use the `\usepackage{wrapfig}` and after `\begin{document}` wrap the figure to put it on the right top corner.

```
\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{0.2\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[scale=0.2]{somepicture.jpg} % No idea on how to position this
\end{wrapfigure}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[UKenglish]{babel}
\usepackage[UKenglish]{isodate}
\usepackage[page]{appendix}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[space]{grffile}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[round]{natbib}
\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}
\usepackage{nopageno}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{datetime}
\usepackage{multicol}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{hidelinks = true,}

\newcolumntype{L}{>{\hsize=.190\hsize}X}
\newcolumntype{R}{>{\hsize=.85\hsize}X}
\newcolumntype{M}{>{\hsize=.28\hsize}X}
\newcolumntype{s}{>{\hsize=.5\hsize}X}

\hyphenpenalty=10000

\setlength\parindent{0pt}

\linespread{1.1}

\setlength{\extrarowheight}{2pt}


\cleanlookdateon

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% PERSONAL DETAILS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h]
    \flushright
\includegraphics[scale=0.2]{example-image-a} % No idea on how to position this
\end{figure}
{\LARGE \textsc{\textbf{Matteo Bulgarelli}}} \\

Updated: {\monthname} \the\year  \\

Via San Pierino 25,\\
40013 Castel Maggiore, Bologna\\
Italy\\
email: \href{mailto:matteo.bulgarelli@student.uclouvain.be}{matteo.bulgarelli@student.uclouvain.be} \\

\medskip
\bigskip

\end{document}
```

[image]